# angular-translate between different views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I started developing an Angularjs web app and I'm using angular-translate in my app and I don't know what is the best way to use angular-translate when I have different views.

I installed angular-translate-loader-static-files on my app and I would like to have a language button on header of my template when clicked change the language of the current view. The views are separated in different controllers and in my index.html:

```
<div ng-controller='HeaderController'>
<button ng-click="changeLanguage('pt')" translate="BUTTON_LANG_PT"></button>
      <button ng-click="changeLanguage('en')" translate="BUTTON_LANG_EN"></button>
</div>
```

My translate module:

```
angular.module('elapApp.translate', ['pascalprecht.translate'])

.config(['$translateProvider', function($translateProvider) {
  // configures staticFilesLoader
  $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
    prefix: 'messages/locale-',
    suffix: '.json'
  });
  // load 'en' table on startup
  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('pt');
}])
.controller('HeaderController', ['$translate', '$scope', function ($translate, $scope) {

  $scope.changeLanguage = function (langKey) {
    $translate.use(langKey);
  };
}]);
```

view.html example:

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <th translate>AUTHOR_NAME</th>
                <th translate>AUTHOR_BIOGRAPHY</th>
                <th translate>AUTHOR_WEBSITE</th>
                <th translate>COMMON_ACTION</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="data in authors">
                    <td>{{data.author_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.author_biography}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.author_website}}</td>
                    <td><a href="#/edit-author/{{data.author_id}}" class="btn">&nbsp;<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit Author</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

And view module:

```
angular.module('elapApp.authors', ['elapApp.services','ngRoute', 'elapApp.translate'])

.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
        title: 'Authors',
        templateUrl: 'partials/authors/authors.html',
        controller: 'AuthorsCtrl'
      }).when('/authors', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/authors/authors.html',
            controller: 'AuthorsCtrl'
        });
    }
])

.controller('AuthorsCtrl', ['$scope', 'Authors', function($scope, Authors) {
    Authors.getAuthors().then(function(data){
        $scope.authors = data.data;
    });

}]).run(['$location', '$rootScope',
    function($location, $rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current, previous) {
            $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
        });
    }
]);
```

So, in this scenario when I clicked on language button every data in my header change language correctly, but in my view nothing happens. How can I change the language of my view in this situation?

Can you help me?

Thanks. All the best!

Comment: I think the API is "$translate.uses" and not "...use" ?

Comment: No @benek , for example you can see http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/07_multi-language

Answer (score 0):

I am new to angular, and i don't see where you defined the view, is it in HeaderController's scope?

I think at least HeaderController should cover view.html, format like:

```
<div ng-controller='HeaderController'>
   <ng-view>
</div>
```